# Do all tumour variants affect the disease pathway

Tags: genetics, cancer, variant

I have analysed some lung tumour samples for somatic variants which generated a list of genes affected by those variants. I tried to analyse KEGG pathways to see what could they disrupt. However, many of the affected genes cause neurological diseases and some cause congenital structural defects. I believe these genes would not be expressed given the location of the tumour. I suppose they will be inaccessible so they would not affect the individual. Is it true or there's something else going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Biology is complicated. It's hard to say without looking at the list of genes. Or indeed, even with the list of genes.

What you are calling a "disease pathway" might instead just be a list of parts that cause cancer when they are broken. There is no guarantee that that list of parts is complete. But as you seem to guess it is hard to conclusively demonstrate causality without either experiments or corroborating information (such as finding genes previously known to cause cancer). For example, [this page writes](https://www.cancer.gov/news-events/cancer-currents-blog/2018/oncoarray-genetic-variants-cancer-risk):

> A recent study published in Nature Genetics, for example, found 10 new variants associated with lung cancer, and studies published in Nature and Nature Genetics found 72 new variants associated with breast cancer.

> In the case of breast cancer, 10 of the risk variants are associated specifically with the risk of developing estrogen receptor-negative disease, which tends to have a poor prognosis and for which few genetic influences were previously known.

So only 10/72 of their variants fit into a clear mechanism! This is pretty standard in the field, is my understanding.

Some people have tried to increase their power in GWAS to detect functional associations by leveraging biological associations between genes, for example [protein-protein interactions](https://journals.plos.org/plosgenetics/article?id=10.1371/journal.pgen.1008903).

While this type of analysis is convenient for variant interpretation, its actual truth is difficult to interpret (for me at least). But it might provide some path forward.

**Update**

As an aside: you should be able to directly check the expression of genes. You don't have to guess/doubt that the genes are expressed. There are [anatomical atlases of gene expression](https://www.proteinatlas.org/), though in cancerous dysregulation some additional genes may also be expressed. Alternately, you could just directly measure expression, assuming that you still have samples.

Comment: Is [this](https://www.nature.com/articles/nmeth.2651) what you're thinking of?  They write they have a package including networks for small cell lung cancer available for download, though I was getting a "page can't be found" just now.

Comment: @MikeSerfas I wasn't thinking of that specifically, more reflecting that this is a generic method that people use for association results when there isn't a clear pathway. However, that ref does seem pretty relevant to the asker. I do see that they include a ZIP archive of matlab code, which I was able to download (proprietary, so possibly not too useful): https://www.nature.com/articles/nmeth.2651#Sec24